# Formatting Timestamp in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to format a `Timestamp` object using:

```
new SimpleDateFormat(
    "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a",
    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Timestamp(0));
```

But this results in formatting it as my explicit pattern no matter what.  I want it to reverse the day and month for the locales where that is common.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s = new SimpleDateFormat(
   "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a",
   Locale.getDefault()).format( new Timestamp(0));
System.err.println( s );
```

What's printed?

If you want to have the default formatting with Locale order, don't specify it:

```
String s = new SimpleDateFormat().format( new Timestamp(0));
System.err.println( s );
```

Documentation [SimpleDateFormat()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28%29).

Comment: It prints like this "10/2/2013 5:05:22 PM" no matter what Locale I set.

Comment: And what did you expect? You impose the format... It may vary if you want the names of the day in week or the names of the month. Your format is only numeric.

Comment: Well, since the constructor took a Locale parameter, I expected it to try and match my format string to a localized pattern.  But upon reading the docs, I see the Locale is just used for getting the localized DateFormatSymbols and Calendar.